# Toggle Two classes using mat-slide-toggle

Tags: javascript, angular-material

Toggle two classes `d-block` and `d-none` using `mat-slide` toggle. When toggled is checked I need to change the `d-none` class to `d-block` and `d-block` to `d-none`

```
<mat-slide-toggle >
  View All Statuses
</mat-slide-toggle>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 d-block">
      <svg id="bar-chart" width="550" height="300"></svg>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 d-none">
      <svg id="stacked-bar-chart" width="550" height="300"></svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I need to toggle d-block and d-none classes using mat -slide toggle

Comment: No its not a duplicate, as over here i need to change two classes which are on different div

Comment: do you want to do by javascript

Comment: @Udhay, yes please help me out as i am new in javascript or provide me some reference example

Comment: do you want to toggle the class based on mat-slide toggle click event

Comment: @Udhay, Yes when the toggle is checked both the "d-block" class should be "d-none" and "d-none" class should be "d-block"

Comment: @Curious-Developer check the below answer. Instead of click event you can add onchange event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this it will works, otherwise you can use `[ngClass]="bool ? 'd-block' : 'd-none'"`

```js
$("#toggleclick").click(function () {
    if($(".d-block").hasClass("hide"))
    {
      $(".d-block").removeClass("hide");
      $(".d-none").addClass("hide");
    }
    else if($(".d-none").hasClass("hide")) {
      $(".d-none").removeClass("hide");
      $(".d-block").addClass("hide");
    }
})
```

```css
.d-block{
  background:#ff0;
}

.d-none{
background:#0ff;
}

.hide{
  display:none;
}

mat-slide-toggle{
cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<mat-slide-toggle id="toggleclick">
  View All Statuses
</mat-slide-toggle>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 d-block">
      <svg id="bar-chart" width="550" height="300"></svg>
      D-Block
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 d-none hide">
      <svg id="stacked-bar-chart" width="550" height="300"></svg>
      D-None
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code using Angular's `ngClass`directive

HTML:

```
<mat-slide-toggle [(ngModel)]="checked">
  View All Statuses
</mat-slide-toggle>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12" [ngClass]="checked ? 'd-none' : 'd-block'">
      <svg id="bar-chart" width="550" height="300"></svg>Hello
    </div>
    <div class="col-12" [ngClass]="checked ? 'd-none' : 'd-block'">
      <svg id="stacked-bar-chart" width="550" height="300"></svg>World
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.d-block {
    display: block;
}

.d-none {
    display: none;
}
```